# Split collapsed value in dataset into separate rows based on specific separate sign

Tags: r

I have dataset like this:

```
structure(list(variable = c("avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::form.childpresent | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childpresent | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::form.childpresent", 
"avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childrenrepeat.childrengroup.dobsourceotherdoc | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::dobsourceotherdoc | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::dobsourceotherdoc", 
"avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::notreatreasonother | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::notreatreasonother | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childrenrepeat.childrengroup.notreatreasonother", 
"avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::dobsourcewho | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::dobsourcewho | avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childrenrepeat.childrengroup.dobsourcewho"
), IRI = c("http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/EUPATH_0050599", "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/EUPATH_0050607", 
"http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/EUPATH_0050582", "http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/EUPATH_0049212"
)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried the code like this:

```
oldcon2<-separate_rows(oldcon,variable, sep=" | ")
```

which oldcon is the original file I duplicated above and oldcon2 is the new one, ideally has all splitted value.

So how can I separate column "variable" based on collapsed sign "|" and put each variable in its own row? Thanks a lot~~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could add this to your code:

The`\\s*\\|\\s*` regex matches zero or more spaces before and after the `|` separator:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

oldcon2 %>% 
  separate_rows(variable, sep = "\\s*\\|\\s*")
```

```
 variable                                                                                               IRI             
   <chr>                                                                                                  <chr>           
 1 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::form.childpresent                                    http://purl.obo…
 2 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childpresent                                    http://purl.obo…
 3 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::form.childpresent                                    http://purl.obo…
 4 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childrenrepeat.childrengroup.dobsourceotherdoc  http://purl.obo…
 5 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::dobsourceotherdoc                                    http://purl.obo…
 6 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::dobsourceotherdoc                                    http://purl.obo…
 7 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::notreatreasonother                                   http://purl.obo…
 8 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::notreatreasonother                                   http://purl.obo…
 9 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childrenrepeat.childrengroup.notreatreasonother http://purl.obo…
10 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 3::dobsourcewho                                         http://purl.obo…
11 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 2::dobsourcewho                                         http://purl.obo…
12 avenir census and treatment data clinepi round 1::form.childrenrepeat.childrengroup.dobsourcewho       http://purl.obo…
```